# jquery mobile slide panel - swipe event on area containing an iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, iframe, swipe

I'm implementing the [jquery mobile slide panel](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/examples/panels/panel-swipe-open.html) into a mobile web application.
It works perfectly aside from a minor swiping issue I can't seem to fix, even though the solution should be pretty much straight forward..

When swiping accross the document the panel opens pretty much instantly (with a 1 second lag on a mobile device):

```
$(document).on( "swiperight", function( e ) 
{
    $( "#nav-menu" ).panel( "open" );       
});
```

But I am loading the content of the pages through an iframe. The area containing the iframe won't allow me to "swipe" open the slide panel. I assumed I could have fixed this by changing 'document' to 'iframe' or 'iframe#content-frame':

```
$('iframe').on( "swiperight", function( e ) 
{
    $( "#nav-menu" ).panel( "open" );       
});
```

But I just can't seem to get this to work..

So, question 1: How do I open a slide panel by swiping on an area that contains an iframe? (The panel should open up on the parent page. Not inside of the iframe).
And question 2: How can i solve the performance/lagging issue I'm having?

Your help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix the swiping issue by posting a message from the page within the iframe, like this:

```
$(document).on( "swiperight", function( e ) 
{
    parent.postMessage("SwipePageMessage","*");
});
```

In the parent page I'm listening for any message that is being send.

```
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
    $( "#nav-menu" ).panel( "open" );       
},false);
```

It works just fine, but I'm not very pleased with implementing this function inside every page.